# Set suzy gutters for a certain file / grouped set of classes?

Tags: susy

I know that you can set gutters for a suzy grid globally:

```
$susy: (
   columns: 12,
   gutters: 0.32,
}
```

And you can also override this for a particular class:

```
.something {
  @include span(1 of 3);
  @include gutters(1em);
}
```

But can you override gutters for certain file?

If the code below was a simplified version of my code what would be the shortest way of making row1s have a different gutter to row2s?

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="row1">
        // Something
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
        // Something
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="row1">
                // Something
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                // Something
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                // Something
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="row2">
        // Something
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        // Something
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="row2">
                // Something
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                // Something
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                // Something
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `with-layout` function to set up a special grid for any group of content:

```
$susy: (gutters: 0.3);
// everything out here will use 0.3 gutters...

@include with-layout((gutters: 0.5)) {
  // everything in here will use 0.5 gutters...  
  .row2 {
    @include span(3);
  }
}

// everything out here will use 0.3 gutters again...
```

The mixin accepts any standard Susy grid map (used above) or grid shorthand as an argument. You can get more detail [from the docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#with-layout).